# Pass messages and/or objects between different storyboards swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've two storyboards and need to pass messages and objects. I know how to do it in the same storyboard and with .xib files, but not with two different storyboards.

My code is:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "RecibosStoryboard", bundle: nil)
        var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RecibosStoryboard") as! UINavigationController

    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil).

    // If i do: var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RecibosStoryboard") as! = TableRecibosViewController -> fails ->cannot convert TablaRecibosViewController to UINavigationController

// If i do:

/* var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RecibosStoryboard") as! UINavigationController


 let vartest: TablaRecibosTableViewController = TablaTablaRecibosTableViewController() 

prueba.inicioPrueba(str, strPrueba2: str2) -> two objects are nill

self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil).

 Two objects are nill*/
```

My second storyboard is "RecibosStoryboard" and only has 1 view who class is TablaRecibosViewController and has a contructor method:

```
class TablaRecibosTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet var tablaRecibos: UITableView!
    var pruebaMansajes: String?
    var pruebaMansajes2: String?

    var arrayOfObjectsCellRecibos: [ObjectTableRecibos] = [ObjectTableRecibos] ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tablaRecibos.dataSource = self
        tablaRecibos.delegate = self

        println("Pruebas satisfactorias1 \(pruebaMansajes) \(pruebaMansajes2)")
    }

    func inicioPrueba(strprueba1:String, strPrueba2:String){
    pruebaMansajes = strprueba1
    pruebaMansajes2 = strPrueba2
    }
```

When i execute the App or crash or print two objects = nil

I don't find the way to do. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following "cannot convert TablaRecibosViewController to UINavigationController". Your TablaRecibosViewController is embedded inside a UINavigationController. Try the following:

```
if let recibosViewController = (storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RecibosStoryboard") as? UINavigationController).viewControllers.first as? TablaRecibosTableViewController {
    recibosViewController.pruebaMensajes = "Hola mundo"

}
```

You were creating a new instance of TablaTablaRecibosTableViewController() which was not associated to the Storyboard, therefore the table view was nil and it crashed.

Comment: I can't do it with you code. I had no other choice that put the View in the same Storyboard :(. For curiosity, if someone knows how to do it, i think than this will help anyone. Thanks